# Sharing notes to friends using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to share notes which will only be able to be viewed by my friends. I have a table called `Friends` where the id of the users are 
[image]

I am trying to share notes between friends, I am able to share notes but when ever I view the notes, I see double because I have 2 friends

```
if ($friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one`='$my_id2' OR `user_two`='$my_id2'")) {

    while ($fetch_friends = mysql_fetch_assoc($friend_query)) {
        $user_one = $fetch_friends['user_one'];
        $user_two = $fetch_friends['user_two'];


        /*QUERY FOR SHARE */
        $displaying_shared_query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `share` WHERE `shared_user_ID` ='$user_one' OR `shared_user_ID` ='$user_two' ");
        while ($fetch_shared_display = mysql_fetch_assoc($displaying_shared_query)) {
            $shared_id2 = $fetch_shared_display['id']; //PRIMARY ID FOR SHARING 
            $shared_note2 = $fetch_shared_display['shared_note'];
            $shared_username2 = $fetch_shared_display['shared_username']; /*UserName of user who is sharing notes*/
            $shared_user_ID2 = $fetch_shared_display['shared_user_ID']; /*ID of user who is sharing notes */
            $shared_Time2 = $fetch_shared_display['time_shared'];


            $del_share = "  <a id='closebtn' href='delete_shared_note.php?note=$shared_id2'><span id='del_share_pix'>Delete</span></a>";
            $from_pic = '<img id="post_dp" src="/user/'.$shared_username2.
            '/display_pic.jpg">';

            //2             //2

            if ($my_id2 == $shared_user_ID2) /*if the shared note is mine than display Delete Option Or ELse Dont */ {

                echo "<span  ><a id='username_text' href='profile.php?user=$shared_user_ID2'>$shared_username2</a></span><br>";
                echo "<a id='post_userName'>$from_pic<br>";
                echo "$shared_Time2 <br>";
                echo "<div class='divbutton' id='share_border'>$shared_note2 $del_share </div><br>";

            } else if ($my_id2 != $shared_user_ID2) {
                echo "<span ><a id='username_text' href='profile.php?user=$shared_user_ID2'>$shared_username2 </a></span><br>";
                echo "<a id='post_userName'>$from_pic<br>";
                echo "$shared_Time2 <br>";
                echo "<div class='divbutton' id='share_border'>$shared_note2 </div><br>";

            }
        }
    }
  }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: The more Friends a user has thats the amount of time the notes would be shared

Answer (score 1):

This data model is not optimal, however I think you can skip the whole outer loop that you've shared with us, and cut to the meat.  Write a SQL query that finds everything shared with you based on who you're friends with.  It's better not to do SQL queries in a loop anyway, since you're exponentially increasing your database hits that way.

```
SELECT * FROM `share` 
WHERE `shared_user_ID`  = '$my_id2' 
OR  `shared_user_ID` 
IN ( SELECT `user_one` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_two` = '$my_id2')
OR  `shared_user_ID` 
IN ( SELECT `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one` = '$my_id2')
```

Let me know if this query doesn't work out for you, I can install mysql and try to replicate your data model to verify it then.

Comment: i am sorry but i do not understand your answer i mean how am i suppose to layout my code please if its possible for you to be more clear thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also, position your WHILE better. Else you will keep getting more and more multiples. Try it out or let me know if you need more help :).